# javafx replacing a row in TableView from a generated string

Tags: javafx, tableview

Im new to Java and JavaFX and Im trying to check it there is a duplicate in a Tableview, and if that is the case I would like to replace it with a new set of data.

So in essence I'm trying to iterate through the data in my TableView and compare it to something. To be more exact I'd like to compre a value of the String on the first column to a new String. I've done some research and I've found that the most common kind of solution for Filtering Data is using a `FilteredList` but this doesn't return my original set of items.

my current Code looks like this:

```
@FXML private TableView<STable> TableV;
public void Replace(String s){
    ObservableList<STable> getCurrentData;
    for(int i = 0; i < getCurrentData.size(); i++){
        // Here is where I get Stuck I've tried: 
        //TableV.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getCajas();
        //getCurrentData.get(i)
        }
    }
```

Note: The STable is a class that has all the setters and getters for each of the columns, I've also got the CellFactory set up.

Any guidance on how to do this would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you just have to iterate through your data items, and compare the value representing the content of column 1, to your new string. If both values are equal, you update the value in your dataModel:

(I replaced STable with YourData, because I find the name for a dataModel a little confusing)

```
for (YourData data : tableView.getItems()) {
    if (data.getColumOne().equals(textToCompare)) {
       data.setColumnOne("newText");
    }
}
```

Or if you want to replace the row:

```
for (int idx = 0; idx < tableView.getItems().size(); idx++) {
    YourData data = tableView.getItems().get(idx);
    if (data.getColumnOne().equals(textToCompare)) {
       tableView.getItems().set(idx, someOtherData);
       return;
    }
}
```